# Select a radio button functional test Symfony2

Tags: symfony, functional-testing

I'm making some functional tests with symfony2. I want to select a radio button in a basic form :

```
<form method="post" action="mylink">
    <input id="position_51" type="radio" name="user_position" value="51"> 
    <input id="position_52" type="radio" name="user_position" value="52"> 
    <input id="position_54" type="radio" name="user_position" value="54"> 
    <input id="position_57" type="radio" name="user_position" value="57"> 
    <button id="bt_submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So I select the form

```
$buttonFrom = $client->getCrawler()->selectButton('bt_submit');
$form = $buttonFrom->form();
```

Now, if I want to select radio with a specific ID, like "position_54" and tick it. How to do? In all examples I found, tick() seem to be used in the name attribute of the input... That not help me in a radio button case.

$form['user_position'] doesn't seem to be a array...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the symfony [doc about testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html), you can select an option or a radio this way :

```
$form['user_position']->select('51');
```

Here is the API for the [ChoiceFormField](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Field/ChoiceFormField.html#method_select).

Comment: oh, nice I think I missread the doc. Thinking tick was for radio :) Thanks!